# dialog has not dismiss() in onitemclick listener

Tags: android

AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
has not (or not showing) dismiss() method under setOnItemClickListener() ??

particularly this is my code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
dialog.setTitle("TITLE");
dialog.setView(view);
dialog.show();

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    dialog.dismiss() // dismiss is not there.


    }
});
```

thanks.

Comment: Your dialog variable is out of scope in the OnItemClickListener. If you want to do this you need to have dialog be an instance variable. Also, how are you sure that the dialog is showing when an item in your listview is clicked?

Comment: as I called dialog.show() , and I see that the dialog is shown and listView contains all I wanted to contain. in that way I'm sure that dialog is visible.

Comment: and dialog is not out of scope because when i call dialog. it shows bunch of its methods but for some reason dismiss is not there. what is the way to close a dialog by pressing an item on listview.  (thanks for your help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what always do in these handlers:

- Create the dialog and have a member variable at the class/activity level
- Create a private method in the class/activity to dismiss the dialog
- Call this private method in your handler

---

What you are creating is not a Dialog, it is DialogBuilder. You need to create it as below:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
builder.setTitle("...");
builder.setMessage("message");
builder.setNegativeButton("OK", null);
AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
```

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this) does not have dismiss(). that method is part of DialogInterface. How can I connect my created dialog with DialogInterface. to use dismiss. I tried your way but still not there.

Comment: Wow yes. Thanks man, your code worked with very minor change, I declared AlertDialog dlg as final. thanks again. by the way both words "ali" and "ostad" is very familiar to me.